# Same MultiIndex DataFrame constructed doesn't aggregate (mean)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

### Short Question:

I am trying to get mean of a column (Data Series) after grouping a Multi-Indexed Pandas DataFrame in two different ways. Difference being only the construction of the DataFrame. One gives me the desired result, the other gives an error `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

### Description:

Common data for construction

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
indexTuples = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('c', 3), ('b', 8)]
multiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(indexTuples, names = ['x', 'y'])
```

#### Constructing the DataFrame by method 1

```
columns = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
df = pd.DataFrame(index=multiIndex, columns=columns)

alpha = pd.Series(index=multiIndex)
beta = pd.Series(index=multiIndex)
gamma = pd.Series(index=multiIndex)

for tup in indexTuples:
    alpha[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)
    beta[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)
    gamma[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)

df.alpha = alpha
df.beta = beta
df.gamma = gamma

df.alpha['a'] = np.nan

df
```

Gives the dataframe which looks like the following

```
     alpha   beta  gamma
x y                     
a 1    NaN  136.0  224.0
b 3  375.0  227.0  191.0
a 2    NaN  367.0  195.0
c 2  247.0   61.0   78.0
  3  238.0  187.0  366.0
b 8  302.0   14.0  272.0
```

and if I do the following operation, I get the expected result

```
df.groupby(level='x').alpha.mean()
```

**Result**

```
x
a      NaN
b    148.0
c    244.5
Name: alpha, dtype: float64
```

#### Constructing the DataFrame by method 2

```
columns = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
_df = pd.DataFrame(index=multiIndex, columns=columns)

for tup in indexTuples:
    _df.alpha[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)
    _df.beta[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)
    _df.gamma[tup[0], tup[1]] = np.random.randint(400)

_df.alpha['a'] = np.nan
```

Gives a similar looking DataFrame with `NaN` values as shown in previous method

But now when I try to find the mean after grouping by level

```
_df.groupby(level='x').alpha.mean()
```

I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-192-ad2de6450fab> in <module>()
----> 1 _df.groupby(level='x').alpha.mean()

/film/tools/packages/pandas/0.18.0/CentOS-6.2_thru_7/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in mean(self)
    933         """
    934         try:
--> 935             return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
    936         except GroupByError:
    937             raise

/film/tools/packages/pandas/0.18.0/CentOS-6.2_thru_7/python-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.18.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only)
    750 
    751         if len(output) == 0:
--> 752             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
    753 
    754         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, names)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Why is it working in the first case and not in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you constructed `_df`, it's `dtype` became `object`.  This happens because as you defined `_df` you didn't initiate it with any data and defaulted to `object`.  In construction #1, you overcame this by assigning `series` constructed independently with values and consequently float type.  In construction #2, you explicitly assigned to `_df` locations with data.  Those locations were already deemed to be `object`.

```
_df.dtypes

alpha    object
beta     object
gamma    object
dtype: object
```

Use this to get your result:

```
_df.astype(float).groupby(level='x').alpha.mean()
```

Comment: somehow **dtype** doesn't work on my dataFrame, but you solution works ! rightly pointed as the dtype issue   

    `_df.dtype

    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Comment: that's my typo.  It should be dtypes (plural for dataframe)